# How to log file system I/O operations?

Tags: c#, io, filesystems

How to log file system input-output operations?

The reason is to find hot and cold file system blocks. Could you suggest me what API or OS subsystems to use from C#?

Answer (score -1):

Using the [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher), you can track what's happening in the file system.

[Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26528/C-Application-to-Watch-a-File-or-Directory-using-F)'s an example that facilitates what you're looking for.

This is what it outputs:

[image]

You achieve this by attaching and handling events exposed by the `FileSystemWatcher`:

```
m_Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
m_Watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
m_Watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
m_Watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
m_Watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
```

You can some info about reading of files as well:

You can set the NotifyFilter-property to LastAccess, and catch the Changed-event. Like this:

```
FileSystemWatcher lWatcher = 
  new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop", "myfile.txt");
lWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess;
lWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(HandlerWatcherChanged);

void HandlerWatcherChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   // file has been accessed
}
```

If you need lower level control over the file system, such as file system blocks, you might find P/Invokes in *kernel32.dll* that achieve this.

Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363983) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516#data_access_and_storage).

[Here](http://pinvoke.net/index.aspx)'s a good place to learn about P/Invokes.

Comment: Hi Shimmy, I need to log at the level below - at file system blocks.

Comment: If I'm reading the documentation you linked correctly, that only detects *writes* to a filesystem.  Reads are just as important.